# Using IE, Jsonp and OpenID how can I get the data sending server to see the client as authenticated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, openid, jsonp

I am constructing an app that collects data from different domains via JSONP. These sites are secured via OpenId. Once I have previously logged in to those sites and my client has the OpenId cookie, both Firefox and Chrome will see me as authenticated and send me my data.

IE 9, however does not see me as authenticated and sends the login page back instead of the data.

Is there anything I can do, any special mode of IE I can use, to allow IE to pass back that token with the JSONP request?

Answer (score 0):

IE does not allow 3rd party cookies unless the server has a privacy policy set in the header.

I've built KitGUI as a 3rd party injectable CMS and I had to overcome this issue. I'm using named item P3P with value as CP="CURa ADMa DEVa OUR DSP OTI COR" in my server header.

The problem is if you don't control the server you are consuming your are **SOL**.

Comment: What does the actual header look like? that is the so called "short form" of p3p?

Comment: What I sent you is the header, exactly. The P3P is the name of the header item and the CP... part is the value. This is all you need for IE to work assuming you can control what the server header is. I don't know how if you are consuming it.